# can i a make an object immutable without using Object.freeze()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solver

## immutables objects

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

// Write Code Here To Pr(event Changing Of Property C Value

myObject.c = 100;
console.log(myObject.c); // 3
```

i am trying to return the value 3 instead  100 without using the Object.freez() method